# Is there a way to create an object using a function inside a class like: bullets[i] = new player1.bullet();?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

If I have a class, class Player1, and this code:

```
let player1;
let bullets = [];

function setup() {

        createCanvas(400, 400);
        player1 = new Player();
}

function draw() {

        player1.logic();
        player1.show();
        for(let i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++) {
            bullets[i].logic();
            bullets[i].show();
}

function keyPressed() {

        switch(keyCode) {
            case 32:
                b = new player1.bullet();
                bullets.push(b);
        }
}
```

Can i somehow put in my class this function 'new player1.bullet();' ??

I want this because I can take some player1 arguments and give it to the bullet;

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a property to the property of class using [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) keyword. So you can bind bullet to class as :

```
player1.prototype.bullet = function() {
    // Function application goes here
}
```

This can be called as `player1.bullet()`. You would not require new keyword for calling the function

Comment: Thank you very much, I knew about prototypes but I didin't knew it had this purpose. Thank you very much;

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, a function can be used as a constructor ([See more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)).

So inside the object you construct you can put another constructor function for another object.

```js
function Player(name) {
  var _name = name;
  this.playerData = "some data of " + _name;

  this.Bullet = function() {
    this.bulletData = "some more data of " + _name;
  }
}

var player1 = new Player("Alice");
console.log(player1);

var player2 = new Player("Bob");
console.log(player2);

var bullet1 = new player1.Bullet();
console.log(bullet1);

var bullet2 = new player2.Bullet();
console.log(bullet2);
```

Comment: Thank you very much too.